# Mux rtsp audio and video from wowza example stream

Tags: gstreamer

Cant get video and audio in one pipeline. I just recently started working with GStreamer. I want someone to give me a hint about what I am doing wrong?

I tried to use `rtpptdemux` but I get only black window :(

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov latency=0 droponlatency=1 ! rtpptdemux name=demux ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink demux. ! queue ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink`

I want to get video and also audio in one pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rtpptdemux` handles a single stream only. It is the `rtspsrc` that has all the media. Try this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov \
latency=0 droponlatency=1 name=rtp_source ! queue ! rtpptdemux  ! decodebin ! \
videoconvert ! autovideosink rtp_source. ! queue ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I just changed the pipeline a bit since because I didn't need rtpptdemux: `gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov latency=0 droponlatency=1 name=rtp_source ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink rtp_source. ! queue ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink`